# TagVisualizer not allowing touch meant for the TagVisualization

Tags: c#, wpf, pixelsense, routed-events

my TagVisualizer covers the whole MS Surface window, when a tagged object is placed a TagVisualization (which is merely a dummy list) is shown as it should. However, I can not touch an item from the list if an object is on the surface (using persist and touching the list items after a tagged object is removed works fine).

**I would like to be able to touch a list item while the tagged object is still on the surface.** Would that be possilbe? I have tried the following solutions to no avail:

1. [MS Surface Tag Visualizer steals contact events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743665/ms-surface-tag-visualizer-steals-contact-events/2745622#2745622) - I have placed the list item within a ScatterViewItem and surrounded by the TagVisualizer, but touch is still not recognized
2. [TagVisualizer - when active - blocks Textbox touch Keyboard focus inside a ScatterViewItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981713/tagvisualizer-when-active-blocks-textbox-touch-keyboard-focus-inside-a-scatt?rq=1) - This solution is specific to text entry and I could not apply the solution to my problem
3. [How to user surfaceslider with touch control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013357/how-to-user-surfaceslider-with-touch-control) - Nothing is covering the list items (except the TagVisualizer of course, but disabling its touch capability would also disable the tag recognition
4. [capture Tag visualizer contact event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076280/capture-tag-visualizer-contact-event) - This offers a solution that might work, but I have not been able to get any response to touch events when a tagged object is on the surface.

Thank you!

**Edit:**
The Input Simulator shows that touch input is detected in the general case, it's just not working on the actual surface. On the surface, the TagVisualizer seems to respond to mouse input though.

Also by surface I mean Samsung SUR40